# Index with ops for `LIKE` and `=` queries

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, postgresql-performance

In my Rails 5 with PostgreSQL 9.5 app I have 2 frequent queries:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE lower(varchar_col) = 'some_string' AND int1_col = some_int AND int2_col = some_other_int

-- and

SELECT * FROM table WHERE lower(varchar_col) LIKE 'some_str%' AND int1_col = some_int
```

`table` is about 1.5m rows and quickly growing.

So, I've created 2 indices for both of these queries:

```
CREATE INDEX index_1 ON table USING btree (lower((varchar_col)::text), int1_col, int2_col)

-- and

CREATE INDEX index_2 ON table USING btree (lower((varchar_col)::text) varchar_pattern_ops, int1_col)
```

I have 2 questions, maybe they are a little noob, I'm not good in DB performance:

1.Can I use only one index for both of these queries? Something like:

```
CREATE INDEX index ON table USING btree (lower((varchar_col)::text) varchar_pattern_ops, int1_col, int2_col)
```

Does `varchar_pattern_ops` shows the same performance for `LIKE` and `=` queries? Will PostgreSQL planner use multicolumn index for 3 columns in query for 2 columns?

2.I noticed that Rails generate index with expression `lower((varchar_col)::text`, but my `varchar_col` has `varchar` type, not `text`. Does this matter and Rails made some mistake and I need to write `CREATE INDEX` query to specifically include column type in query?

Thanks for any help!

P.S. Of course, table's, columns' and indices' name are changed for better reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an index which is somewhere between the one suggested by @ypercubeᵀᴹ and your `index_2` ... which would be:

```
CREATE INDEX index_1 ON t 
    USING btree 
          (int1_col, 
          lower((varchar_col)::text) varchar_pattern_ops, 
          int2_col) ;
```

... seems to be a good compromise.

You put first the two columns that you use *always*, and add the third one as the last. You add the `varchar_pattern_ops` so that queries with LIKE use the index.

From the two *always used* columns, put the one which is always tested for equality first, the one which is tested with other operators (>=, <=, like) second. If both were tested for equality, you normally would want to have the one which is more discriminant [which means, more or less, that has a bigger number of different values] first. If several columns are equally discriminant, you put first the ones with the datatypes easier/faster to compare (for instance: fixed-size values such as integers would go before varying length values such as texts).

These are the exeuction plans of the two queries you want to perform:

```
 EXPLAIN ANALYZE
 SELECT 
     * 
 FROM 
     t 
 WHERE 
     lower(varchar_col) = 'some_string' 
     AND int1_col = 5678 
     AND int2_col = 1234 ;
```

```
 | QUERY PLAN                                                                                                     |
 | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
 | Index Scan using index_1 on t  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.007..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)     |
 |   Index Cond: ((int1_col = 5678) AND (lower((varchar_col)::text) = 'some_string'::text) AND (int2_col = 1234)) |
 | Planning time: 0.274 ms                                                                                        |
 | Execution time: 0.023 ms                                                                                       |
```

```
 EXPLAIN ANALYZE
 SELECT * FROM t WHERE lower(varchar_col) LIKE 'some_str%' AND int1_col = 5678 ;
```

```
 | QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                   |
 | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
 | Bitmap Heap Scan on t  (cost=4.44..12.16 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.013..0.015 rows=3 loops=1)                                          |
 |   Recheck Cond: (int1_col = 5678)                                                                                                            |
 |   Filter: (lower((varchar_col)::text) ~~ 'some_str%'::text)                                                                                  |
 |   Heap Blocks: exact=1                                                                                                                       |
 |   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_1  (cost=0.00..4.44 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=3 loops=1)                               |
 |         Index Cond: ((int1_col = 5678) AND (lower((varchar_col)::text) ~>=~ 'some'::text) AND (lower((varchar_col)::text) ~<~ 'somf'::text)) |
 | Planning time: 0.177 ms                                                                                                                      |
 | Execution time: 0.027 ms                                                                                                                     |
```

Both query plans use your index and are fast (although, my simulated data might not be realistic at all).

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=3928d22ef03812484092c2f4e30fd259)*